# Return section of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets say i have a value like this:

```
Z00056ABC00044
```

I would like to know what the values are BEFORE ABC
So my query should return only:

```
Z00056
```

I have tried to create a function:

```
if CHARINDEX('ABC',@mainString) > 0
begin
    --do something
end
```

But i am unsure how to grab the value before ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Z00056ABC00044', 1, CHARINDEX('ABC', 'Z00056ABC00044') -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(@MyValue, (LEN(@MyValue) - CHARINDEX('ABC', @MyValue) - 1))
```

Comment: This will return `Z00056A`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful for you ;

```
select  SUBSTR('Z00056ABC00044', 1, INSTR('Z00056ABC00044', 'ABC')-1) from dual
```

Output :

```
Z00056
```

Comment: This doesn't work in T-SQL ! The OP is specifying that he's using T-SQL and not MYSQL nor PL/SQL.